# node.js synchronous requests for use in caching

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have an issue I need to resolve in my code that has to do with caching API results. I have some async.map like so:

```
for(var user of allUsers) {
    var requestList = fill(cache, locations, apiUrl, cacheMap);

    async.map(requestList, function(obj, callback) {
        // ...
    }, function(err, results) {
        // PUT RESULTS INTO A CACHE
    });
}
```

the function `fill` simply looks within the cache to see if a location in `locations` exists, and it not creates a request URL for my API to be run.

I'm realizing however that a cache won't be much use at all with my approach, because my code will dispatch the async.map and immediately start on the next loop iterations `fill`, meaning the cache won't be synchronized at each iteration of the user.

How would I go about ensuring that each iteration of the user has an updated version of the cache from the last user? I need to make very smart use of my limited API calls, so if there are duplicated requests I want to request once, then pull that result from the cache in later requests.

My only throught right now would be to to a synchronized request instead of an async.map, but I know this goes against the design of node.js.

```
for(var user of allUsers) {
    var requestList = fill(cache, locations, apiUrl, cacheMap);

    // sync map instead
    requestList.map(function(obj) {
        var res = sync-request(obj)
        // put request result into cache
    });

    // cont...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just iterate over `allUsers` using [async.eachSeries](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries). This will step through in order and keep it asynchronous.

```
async.eachSeries(allUsers, (user, done) => {
  const requestList = fill(cache, locations, apiUrl, cacheMap);

  async.map(requestList, (obj, callback) => {
    // ..

    callback(null, requestResult);
  }, (err, results) => {
    // PUT RESULTS INTO A CACHE

    done(null, results);
  });
}, cb);
```

Comment: Does it guarantee to run the series in order? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it will be guaranteed order. If you use just `.each`, then it won't be guaranteed as they will be ran in parrallel

Answer (score 2):

Use Promises to proxy and cache the API calls. Batching API requests and caching the results are extremely simple using Promises. The following little module of code wraps an existing `expensiveAPI` call in a Promise and caches the resolved result for 60 seconds.

```
// Existing module to call the expensive API
// using the standard callback pattern
var expensiveApi = require("./expensiveApi");
// Using bluebird promise library
// See http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html
var Promise = require("bluebird");

// Promisify the existing callback
expensiveApi = Promise.promisify(expensiveApi);
// Calls to the API will now return a Promise

// A cache for the Promises
var cache = {};

module.exports = function expensiveApiWithPromises(item) {
  // Check whether a cached Promise already exists
  if (cache[item]) {
    // Return it to the caller
    return cache[item];
  }

  // Promise is not in the cache
  cache[item] = expensiveApi(item)
  .then(function(result) {
    // Promise has resolved
    // set the result to expire
    setTimeout(function() {
      delete cache[item];
    }, 60 * 1000); // 60 seconds expiry
    // Return the result
    return result;
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    // Promise rejected with an error
    // Reset the cache item
    delete cache[item];
    // Propagate the error
    throw err;
  });

  // Return the newly created cached Promise
  return cache[item];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would promisifying a `request()` call work with this code as well? At that point wouldn't I just want to use the `request-promise()` library and chain the `.then()` with it?

Comment: Yes. If your API request is using `request-promise` then you don't need to promisify the API request as it's already going to return a promise.